# Is it possible to return an L-value from a function

Tags: java

As some of you are aware, C++ allows doing this:

```
get( array, 5 ) = 5;
```

with the function `get` implemented something like:

```
int& get( int* array, int index ) { return array[index]; }
```

Is something similar possible in Java? More specifically, I'd like to encapsulate array indexing logic in a function (in a high-performance way).

Comment: Why not just use `array[index] = 5` without any function in between? I don't get how you try to achieve a performance increase like this.

Comment: @noone The point is to **encapsulate array indexing logic**, while *maintaining* good performance.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky if your point is to encapsulate array indexing logic then the one way would be to write a helper class with a method like `setValue(int[] array, int customIndex, int newValue)`. Every solution for an array which use primitive types would be related to this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java passes arguments and return values "by value," which means that C++-style references are not supported. By design, there is no way to tell the compiler "don't copy variable `a`; instead make an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29) to it and let another function use the same memory location and modify my variable if it wants to."

A workaround is to instead pass a reference to a wrapper object. For arrays, the wrapper object would save a reference to the array and an offset. Here is a way using built-in classes:

```
IntBuffer get(int[] array, int index) 
{
    return IntBuffer.wrap( array, index, 1 ).slice();
}

get( array, 5 ).put( 42 );
```

And another (which doesn't work for primitive types):

```
List<Object> get(Object[] array, int index) 
{
    return Arrays.asList( array ).subList( offset, offset + 1 );
}

get( array, 5 ).set( 0, new Object() );
```

This should be just as fast as a straight array access, because the JIT knows how to optimize away all the boiler-plate code.

But since Java does not let you override operator `=`, the syntax is not as nice as we would like.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such option. Non-objects (literals) are primitive types and you cannot simply connect two variables so that when changing one, second becomes also changed.

All objects are represented by its references which you can use to change some attributes of held object. This means that you can code:

```
getMyObject().setX(newXVal);
```

But you cannot write:

```
getMyObject().getX() = newVal;
```

Because method `getX()` (and any method that does not return void) **always returns value type** (when returning `Object` it is its address, when returning literal it's just this literal's value).

If you want to write performance-optimized code in Java - first write, then measure, and then eventually tune it (if measurement step says it's slow). **JVM has enough optimalizations to make your code as fastest as possible, you don't have to optimize code too early.**

Comment: Sorry to sound ungrateful, but this answer is poorly written and confused.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky why confused? Using function-as-a-L-value means you have to use custom wrappers for primitive types. That's rather anti-performance solution.

Comment: You're right that Integer is immutable, a custom wrapper is one solution, and is low-performance. I mean the text is confused. I'll explain. "Non-objects-values (literals)" is non-sensical, not least because "literals" != 'reference type'. "All objects are references...the only way to access it..." is likewise irrelevant. Extending Number is not necessary to create a wrapper. "I would not recommend this option unless you were sure that your code is too slow" seems to say that wrappers would *improve* performance. Generic advice about premature optimization is simply unwelcome.

Comment: Also, please remember that "it's" means "it is" and "its" is the possessive, just like "he's" is "he is" and "his" means "belonging to him."

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky you're right, it was too early for me to write any logical answer :) Now it's corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It not possible. Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them by value.

You can use something like this:

```
public static <T> void setArrayValue(T [] array, int index, T set) {
    ...
}
```